# Private browsing HTTPS page is redirected to HTTP

Tags: firefox, dns, redirection

I am using Firefox 46.0.1.  When I go to https://chriszarate.github.io/supergenpass/mobile/, everything behaves as I would expect.

When I visit the same URL in a private tab, I am redirected to http://www.supergenpass.com/mobile/ (no https).

In the non-private console, the only requests I see are to github.io.  The private console shows a 301 redirect to supergenpass.com

I first noticed this yesterday using Firefox Developer Edition on a different machine (DE displays downgrading behavior, regular edition does not.  Didn't think to try private window).  What might be going on here?

EDIT 5/22/16:
The issue appears to have resolved itself - https://chriszarate.github.io/supergenpass/mobile does not redirect for me.  Unfortunately I don't know why it does this, or why it didn't before. ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: Why are you going to the mobile site on a desktop browser?  I should point out that Chrome redirected me to `http://www.supergenpass.com/mobile/`.  I can't even vist a secure connection to `http://www.supergenpass.com/mobile/` sounds like a server configuration problem.  What I can tell is that certificate is for github.com instead of supergenpass.com

Comment: Supergenpass is a bookmarklet. If it won't load on a particular site, it prompts you to use the mobile site.

What's confusing to me is why a private window would exhibit different behavior than a regular window.

Comment: Both my Firefox, Safari and Chrome behave the same as Ramhound describes...

Comment: In that case, why might my Firefox _not_ be redirecting?

Comment: @Wiscocrew - Which is the point of my comment.  I cannot reproduce any behavior other then what I described, which is what you claim, only happens while in private mode.

Comment: The opposite, rather - it redirects in private mode, does not in regular. In any case, I can't figure out what's going on. That's what I was hoping for an answer for -_-